# Sublime / LESS-Build error when compile bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, sublimetext2

I have problems with compile less on sublime text 2 with LESS-Build plugin, less normaly works but when i want build bootstrap from less sources sublime response me this error:

```
[Compile]
C:\test\assets\css\main.less -> C:\test\assets\css\main.css

Expected ')' but found ' ' on line 20 in file 'less/mixins/image.less':
 [19]: // spelling of `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio` is intentional.
 [20]: .img-retina(@file-1x; @file-2x; @width-1x; @height-1x) {
       --------------------^
 [21]:   background-image: url("@{file-1x}");
[Done - Failed]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

How to repair this?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The [LESS-build-sublime](https://github.com/berfarah/Less-build-sublime) plugin seems to use the [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) LESS compiler. This .NET LESS compiler supports the language features up to version 1.3.0.

The source code of Bootstrap however uses a LESS compiler at version 2.1.0. Bootstrap depends on one of the language features that doesn't exist in version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution to get to me, is to compile bootstrap with CMD or MSDOS windows in this case!

**what did I do?**

nodejs and then install this install with the same nodejs Less to compile this course ...

After that grab the folder Less bootstrap place it in a folder called `Bootstrap/` but the content of all this is that with Less developed bootstrap
then the project I think my "theme" folder and my files there like Less bootstrap.less think my folder theme.less and modules as mixins or whatever name
At first all I do is concatenate the `bootstrap.min.css`

for not using all the time the CMD to be compiled since the dotless pressing `crt+B` compiles faster

to finish my project in the "theme" I take out my wallet with my code Less folder and put it in the same folder where the Bootstrap containing Less
in turn put the "theme" folder that just have less and in a file I call arparte style.less or name you want I place

```
@import "bootstrap / bootstrap.less";
@import "theme / efix.less";
```

After that if I go there and compiled in the CMD with the command

```
lessc xxx.less xxx.css
```

Significantly hubicacion must be in the same file

that is to say

```
xampp/htdocs/projects/test/
```

I hope this can help because so many try to compile the bootstrap with my own code Less "Using Less-build" or dotless Sublime Text and could not in any way

***Excuse my bad English, use the google translate as my first language is Spanish***